# I can't find format file 'pdflatex.fmt'!

Tags: pdftex, linux, format-files, linuxfedora

I'm on Fedora Silverblue 39 and used `rpm-ostree` to install `texlive-scheme-full`.

I tried compiling a .tex file from the command line using `pdflatex` but it returns this error.

```
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
mktexfmt: mktexfmt is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
mktexfmt:   /var/home/stevicheliz/.texlive2023/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
mktexfmt [INFO]: writing formats under /var/home/stevicheliz/.texlive2023/texmf-var/web2c
mktexfmt [INFO]: Did not find entry for byfmt=pdflatex skipped
mktexfmt [INFO]: total formats: 0
mktexfmt [INFO]: exiting with status 0
I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!
```

I searched online and tried running `sudo fmtutil -sys --all` which returned:

```
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf files (in precedence order):
fmtutil: fmtutil is using the following fmtutil.cnf file for writing changes:
fmtutil:   /usr/share/texlive/texmf-config/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
fmtutil [INFO]: writing formats under /var/lib/texmf/web2c
fmtutil [WARNING]: You seem to have no formats defined in your fmtutil.cnf files!
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 0
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 0
```

The file still won't compile.

I tried reinstalling `texlive-scheme-full` and it still returned the same error. I also tried uninstalling `texlive-scheme-full` and installing `texlive-scheme-basic` and it still wouldn't compile. `rpm-ostree` automatically updates all packages before installing so there shouldn't be any dependency problems. Even so I did a system update, rebooted, installed texlive and rebooted again. Still won't compile.

Edit: `fmtutil.cnf` does not exist on either of the paths logged.

Comment: what is the content of the two `fmtutil.cnf` mentioned in your logs?

Comment: They don't exist.

Comment: I use Linux as a jailed subsystem of Android. When I first started with this, sometimes I would see error messages like you have. The problem was that the TeX environment variables (TEXMFDIST, etc.) would be changed, depending on how and when I got the code, because the paths were different in distro and in jailed Linux. Maybe something similar is happening in your case? Use `\kpsewhich` to discover the TeX environment varaibles. Do they match what is requested in the TeX installation scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed `tex-live` through `tug.org` and post-install it recommended to install the LWP bundle. It turns out Fedora Silverblue doesn't have any perl packages apart from perl itself. As soon as I installed the perl essentials and LWP, I could compile without a hitch. `fmtutil-sys` also worked like a charm afterwards, though I had to fiddle around with `sudo` to get it to find tex commands.